# get function arguments count from external scope

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get function arguments count from external scope?

```
var foo = function(a,b,c) {
}

alert(foo.arguments.length); // how to do it? possible?
```

Comment: You want the number of expected parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length):

```
function test(a, b, c) {
  // code
}

console.log(test.length); // 3
```

BTW, the number of expected arguments of a function is called the *arity*. There used to be a method called [`Function.arity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arity) but was deprecated in favour of `Function.length`.

Answer (score 3):

try `foo.length`. It gives no of parameters defined in function definition.

Answer (score 3):

Remove arguments in `foo.arguments.length`

```
foo.length
```